# help, i register script policy with pool.pm was not approved?

Tags: nft, nami-wallet, cardano-serialization-lib

I'm learning to create nft. by using cardano serialization lib and nami wallet
but the nft I created, register script policy with pool.pm was not approved.
I don't know if it's caused by a signed key or not? please advise
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide more information, such as share your policy you try to have approved?

Answer (score 1):

To register a NFT's Policy script in pool.pm you will need to paste your json policy script into the NFT's script text input.

The JSON file should be formatted like this:

```
{
    "type": "all",
    "scripts": [
        {
            "slot": 70000000,
            "type": "before"
        },
        {
            "keyHash": "2bac2f5b08379b3756f594fbce1d3c53565f83b78ab7b106df1f7e950e",
            "type": "sig"
        }
    ]
}
```

If the hash of the json policy script matches the PolicyId then the policy will be verified automatically and the timelock symbol will appear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing two things (at least it's confusing to read from your description)...

The first is entering your policy.script file contents into pool.pm. This will turn the ? into a lock. There is no approval process here - it happens the moment you press submit assuming you did it right.

The second is registering your policy ID with CNFT github: https://github.com/Cardano-NFTs/policyIDs. This does require approval. I know they are SEVERLY backed up from the holidays, so unless your pull request failed then you just have to continue to be patient.